# Numbers stick together as characters

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a dataset with measured values (txt file, whitespace separated) and some numbers stick together like this:

[image]

Currently all columns are of class "character", since after conversion those pasted numbers got "NA"s. I created a routine for negative numbers, which was easy so far:

```
findandreplace <- function(file_name){


dat <- read_table2(file_name, col_names = FALSE)


  for (n in 0:9) {
    dat <- data.frame(lapply(dat, function(x) {gsub(paste0(n, "-"), paste0(n, " -"), x)}))
  }

  #save dat as txt and read it again
}
```

But now, I have no idea how to separate positive values. If you want you can use this MWE:

```
b = c("340.9","341","316.1","336.8316.39","378.8","315","386.57317.33",NA,NA)
a  =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
c  = data.frame(a,b)
```

This is how it should be:

```
b = c("340.9","341","316.1","336.8","316.39","378.8","315","386.57", "317.33")
a  =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
c  = data.frame(a,b)
```

Comment: how do you know its 336.8 and 316.39 for "336.8316.39" and not 336.83 and 16.39

Comment: Because it is temperature measured in small steps. It would not differ that much between two measurements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 x=unlist(strsplit(gsub("(.*)(3(?>\\d{2}\\.))","\\1 \\2",b,perl=T)," "))  
grep("\\d",x,value = T)
[1] "340.9"  "341"    "316.1"  "336.8"  "316.39" "378.8"  "315"    "386.57" "317.33"


transform(c,b=grep("\\d",x,value = T))
  a      b
1 1  340.9
2 2    341
3 3  316.1
4 4  336.8
5 5 316.39
6 6  378.8
7 7    315
8 8 386.57
9 9 317.33
```